# Spark DataFrame: Add a new columns according to other columns

Tags: python, apache-spark

I want to add a new column `new_col`, if the value of column `a` is in `yes_list`, then the value is `1` in `new_col` else `0`

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
rdd = sc.parallelize([{"a":'y'}, {"a":'y', "b":2}, {"a":'n', "c":3}])
rdd_df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

yes_list = ['y']
```

Something like this:

```
rdd_df.withColumn("new_col", [1 if val in yes_list else 0 for val in rdd_df["a"]])
```

But the above is not correct, and raise errors.

```
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `when` and `isin` functions for the sparkSQL API. It would go as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions
rdd_df.withColumn("new_col", functions.when(rdd_df['a'].isin(yes_list), 1).otherwise(0)).show()
```

```
+---+----+----+-------+                                                         
|  a|   b|   c|new_col|
+---+----+----+-------+
|  y|null|null|      1|
|  y|   2|null|      1|
|  n|null|   3|      0|
+---+----+----+-------+
```